# Is there an NCPDP implementation reference standard?

Tags: standards

Is there an NCPDP [National Council for Prescription Drug Programs] implementation reference standard - especially one written in a .NET language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NCPDP publishes several different standards for different purposes and there can be no single answer to this question.  To which are you referring?

Mark

Comment: I am hoping there is a simple reference or open source example of software allowing pharmacy transactions in NCPDP D.0 format. Thanks, Dave

Comment: There was none so I wrote from scratch.